# How to read a QR code directly from a mobile camera using ZXing [ASP.Net WebForm]

Tags: c#, asp.net, zxing

I am currently working on a medical project that consists of a patient database. I used zxing to generate a QR code every time a patient is added into the record and the QR code contains the patient's ID.

The generation code is as follows

```
 //GENERATE QRCODE
        private void GenerateCode(string patientIdString)
        {           

            var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
            writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            var result = writer.Write(patientIdString);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + patientIdString + ".jpg");
            var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);

            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    barcodeBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            patientQRCode.Visible = true;
            patientQRCode.ImageUrl = "~/images/"+ patientIdString + ".jpg";
        }
```

This method is then called on the AddPatient feature which works perfectly fine.

On my Scanning page, I have two features, either a user clicks on a patient's ID that's viewed on a dataTable which would redirect them to the view patient page, or a user has a feature to use their mobile camera.

The code to read the QR Code and translate it is as follows

```
//READ CODE FROM QR IMAGE
        private void ReadQRCode()
        {
            var reader = new BarcodeReader();
            string filename = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~/images/"), "QRImage.jpg");
            //Detatch and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
            var result = reader.Decode(new Bitmap(filename));
            if (result != null)
            {
                lblQRCode.Text = "QR Code : " + result.Text;
            }
        }
```

And the method that I'm using for mobile users to open their camera is as follows:

```
        <p class="lead" style="text-align: center"><input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="file" accept="image/*" runat="server" capture="camera" /></p>
```

The problem is that the camera isn't actually scanning / taking a picture, it merely works as a lense. Is there a way to make it read and convert the code for it to obtain the patient ID and then automatically redirect the user to the patient page?

Thank you in advanced for the support

Comment: Are you just developing the back-end or an accompanying mobile application? if its only the back-end then the user needs to use an app that will scan the QR and you will have the link you want to go to embedded in the QR. (AFAIK some phone cameras do this by default but not all)

Comment: @Kevin I am creating a web-form project that is accessible by any browser (computer / mobile).  No accompanying mobile applications are being used

Comment: I'm sure there are users who will know more than me in regards this, but I don't think you are able to do this from a web form. if you have a device that doesn't have the functionality inbuilt by default it can't work and you don't have access to the device to install your own packages. You could create a very simple QR scanner app that your project redirects to, although obviously that is not ideal.

Comment: Don't take my word as gospel. I am not fully sure that is just my impression from my experience with android development and zxing. Hopefully it is possible and a user will enlighten us both.

Comment: @Kevin how complicated would making a simple QR scanner app be? I don't have too much time develop this so I might not be able to

Comment: Very basic one you should get it done in an hour if you are familiar with ZXing, all you need is an app that when opened will scan the barcode then do something. (Maybe you want a check that it will only scan your barcode) I should have the scan functionality for Xamarin for a project at home, I can send you the relevant bit of code this evening if you would like

Comment: @Kevin I ended up using a WebRTC feature to open the camera and take photos, but the only issue is that It ONLY uses the front-facing camera and won't give me the option to switch to the back. I asked this on another question now (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819958/asp-net-web-form-allows-use-of-front-facing-camera-but-not-back-webrtc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up enabling WebRTC javascript plugin to enable a panel that uses the camera on the phone. (This tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos#Using_specific_devices)

And then used this example to enable the back camera since the first section only allowed the front-facing camera to be used. (https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)

This gave me the desired outcome needed with the image capturing.

I then used ZXing to create the QR needed and then also to read the image that's being captured by the WebRTC camera.

I also remembered that the cameras where displaying a blank screen when I'd try and run the website on my mobile, that turned out to be since the website didn't have the SSL ceritificate verified meaning that the site was still a HTTP rather than a HTTPS which for some reason allows the mobile from accessing the camera feature. (https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/visual-studio-2017-resolving-ssl-tls-connections-problems-with-iis-express)